# Правописание неполных топонимов

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, топонимика

Если автор решает сократить составной топоним, приводя в предложении не первое составляющее его слово, а второе или третье, следует ли его писать с заглавной буквы?

Например, если речь идёт об Александровском саде:

> Буду ждать у входа в Сад.

Answer (score 3):

Александровский сад, Летний сад, Алексеевский (Писаревский) сад — это составные имена собственные, в которых использовано родовое слово "сад".
Оно пишется со строчной буквы, поэтому при употреблении только второй части топонима, думаю, также надо писать строчную букву.

**Буду ждать у входа в сад.**
Но: Встретимся у входа в Александровский (или Летний).

В Северном Ледовитом океане, в залах Русского музея, на берегу Чудского озера, на курортах Краснодарского края, на карте Ленинградской области — в океане, в залах музея, на берегу озера, на курортах края, на карте области.

[Орфография имен собственных](https://info.wikireading.ru/276488)

Comment: Тоже хотел ответить на вопрос. И в качестве примеров строчной буквы собирался привести следующие предложения из [Википедии](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Александровский_сад_(Москва)): _В саду происходит часть действия романа Михаила Булгакова «Мастер и Маргарита». В саду разворачивается действие в начале романа Бориса Акунина «Азазель»._

Comment: Да тут любой пример будет к месту. Скульптуры Аничкова моста. — _В октябре 1941 году после начала блокады **скульптуры моста** было решено закопать..._ Деревья в Летнем саду. — _**В саду** шла, по сути дела, экспериментальная (и не всегда, конечно, удачная) работа по пересадке взрослых деревьев..._