# «Лицей» — с заглавной буквы

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика

В тесте по русскому языку на одном сайте встретил такое предложение:

*Не может не бросаться в глаза, что, когда в дальнейшем Пушкин хотел оглянуться на начало своей жизни, он неизменно вспоминал только **Лицей**.*

Почему слово "Лицей" употреблено с заглавной буквы? Это ведь родовое понятие, а не название конкретного учебного заведения.

Comment: Способ выделить его среди других. Не просто лицей, а именно тот, в котором он учился, о котором у него так много воспоминаний. Не знаю, что за правило, но в художественной литературе периодически встречается, когда некий весьма важный объект, о котором идёт речь, получает написание с большой буквы чтобы подчеркнуть его значимость и уникальность.

Comment: @Qwertiy вообще-то мы здесь све больше именно о правилах рассуждаем. "Способы" без правил не по формату.

Comment: @behemothus, именно поэтому  написал комментарий, а не ответ. К тому же, штука довольно частая, так что я сильно подозреваю, что она является каким-то литературным приёмом, у которого есть своё название.

Answer (score 3):

Правильное предложение ([Ю. М. Лотман.](http://vivovoco.astronet.ru/VV/PAPERS/LOTMAN/PUSHKIN/CHAPT01.HTM) Александр Сергеевич Пушкин: биография писателя) выглядит так:

> Тем более бросается в глаза, что, когда в дальнейшем Пушкин хотел оглянуться на начало своей жизни, он неизменно вспоминал только Лицей — детство он вычеркнул из своей жизни.

Дело, думаю, в том, что первоначально Императорский Царскосельский лицей (с 1843 по 1917 годы — Александровский лицей) назывался просто *Лицей*.
Утверждённое в 1810 г. императором Александром I [**«Постановление о Лицее»**](https://www.prlib.ru/item/438246) уравнивало новое образовательное заведение в правах и преимуществах с российскими университетами.
Этот Лицей был первым и единственным в то время, поэтому вполне понятно, что его название пишется с заглавной буквы — как название конкретного учебного заведения, не нуждающегося ни в каких дополнительных или изменяющихся со временем определениях.

Сам А. С. Пушкин писал («Была пора: наш праздник молодой...» [1936]):

> Вы помните: когда возник Лицей,
> Как царь для нас открыл чертог царицын.
> И мы пришли. И встретил нас Куницын
> Приветствием меж царственных гостей...

P. S. В особом стилистическом употреблении могут писаться с прописной буквы имена нарицательные, например: *Родина, Человек.*
[Прописные буквы](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop#:%7E:text=%C2%A7%20105.,%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0.)

Comment: Согласен с ответом, но всё же. *Сам А. С. Пушкин писал* — это Вы ссылаетесь не на Пушкина, а на редакторов какого-то издания 1936 года. Для примера в ПСС, вышедшем в том же 1936-м, "лицей" написан с маленькой буквы. Но вся эта статистика не имеет отношения к тому, как писал сам А.С. Пушкин. (Впрочем, я не сомневаюсь, что он писал с большой.)

Answer (score 1):

Тут могут быть две трактовки.
Либо это условное имя собственное (наподобие обсуждавшихся слов типа [Устав](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449732)), либо сокращенное имя типа Университет (в отношении МГУ, скажем) - полное название "Царскосельский Лицей" (в этом случае заглавная во втором слове обсуждаема), а сокращенное - Лицей. Пушкинскому духу и времени в принципе соответствуют обе версии.

Для сравнения возьмите, например, "Кунсткамера" или "Эрмитаж". Слова этипри Петре изначально не были именами собственными в чистом виде, использовались скорее как нарицательные, но особые. А теперь воспринимаются именно как собственные. Лицей (тот, пушкинский) вполне может быть из этого ряда.

Что касается особого стилистического употребления (по @РиммаМихайлова), то, боюсь, этот вариант сюда приложить будет трудно. Это "особое употребление" требует какой-то возвышенности, пафосности даже, а в слове Лицей, написанном с заглавной, его нет. Это именно что имя собстветвенное или условное название.

Answer (score 1):

1. Итак, **Импера́торский Царскосе́льский лице́й** — привилегированное высшее учебное заведение для детей дворян в Российской империи, действовавшее в Царском Селе с 1811 по 1843 год. Когда-то на окраине Афин, близ храма Аполлона Ликейского, существовала школа, основанная великим философом прошлого Аристотелем. Она называлась **Ликеем или Лицеем**. 19 октября 1811 года учебное заведение под этим же названием открылось в Царском Селе, близ Петербурга.
2. Но дело не в том, что он назывался Лицеем изначально или так Пушкин его называл,  и даже не в традиции современного названия. Здесь всё **по правилам** (п.7): http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=20#pp20

Правило звучит так:

"С прописной буквы пишется начальное слово **неполного названия**, которое употребляется **в функции полного**: Литературный музей (Государственный литературный музей), Большой театр (Государственный академический Большой театр России), Дом журналиста (Центральный Дом журналиста)".

В нашем случае Лицей — это тот **конкретный** Лицей, который  действовал в Царском Селе с 1811 по 1843 год.

3. Также **в грамматике** существует общее правило для различения **нарицательных и собственных имён**.

Родовое слово ***лицей*** определяется по словарю и является общим названием однородного ряда предметов.  **Имя собственное** – это единичный предмет из этого ряда, имеющее индивидуальное название .

Родовое имя может входить в имя собственное, в этом случае оно пишется со строчной буквы. Но если мы сокращаем имя собственное **до одного слова**, то оно выступает на правах собственного названия.

4. Надо сказать, что написание со строчной буквы ***лицей*** также  используется в статьях, посвященных этой теме. И это обычная практика, так как  читателям уже понятно, о каком конкретном лицее идет речь. Например: «*Воспитанники **лицея** никогда не были праздны. Здесь все было направленно на развитие умственных интересов, поощрялось всякое стремление к знаниям».*

Comment: Дело в том, что у Ю. Лотмана слово "Лицей" (до указанного предложения)  в тексте не только не расшифровывается, но даже не упоминается. С первого раза — и сразу с прописной буквы.

Comment: В том-то и дело. Если автор в статье упоминаете Лицей  первый раз, то читатели имеют право знать, что речь идет о названии конкретного учебного заведения (то есть обозначено  имя собственное).  Но если вы пишете статью на тему Пушкинского лицея (другое название), то в середине статьи можно использовать нарицательное существительное. Такая практика обычна.

Comment: Как же так? У нас ведь нет никакого начального слова. Предположим, речь идет о температуре воды в Северном Ледовитом океане. При "сокращении" до одного слова никто не напишет во втором (или каком-либо другом) предложении "Океан". Или: Государственный академический Большой театр России — не есть "Театр" при повторном упоминании. Или: Таллиннский Линнамяэский Русский лицей — не есть "Лицей".

Comment: Как же так? Да всё очень просто. Мы же люди, а не роботы. Наше мышление не такое быстрое, как у них, зато другого качества. По нескольким признакам мы можем быстрее сканировать предмет, чем наши механические собратья просчитают его все варианты. Если в предложении упоминается Пушкин, то одного этого признака достаточно, чтобы  определить, о каком Лицее идет речь.Поэтому сокращать название можно до определенных пределов, соответственно, океану, театру и даже лицею в Таллине весьма затруднительно стать именами собственными в заданном информационном пространстве.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461392/Правописание-неполных-топонимов/461397#461397 В этой теме обсуждалась возможность написания неполного имени собствееного с заглавной буквы. Когда речь идёт об Александровском саде, можно ди, если читателю известно, что речь идёт о нём, употребить Сад с большой буквы?

Comment: Буду ждать у входа в Сад. В разговорном стиле вполне допустимо, если адресат вас однозначно поймет.